# default value for object in dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I have a dictionary set up like so:  `Dictionary <string, ItemProperties>`

the ItemProperties object looks like this (the base class is abstract):

```
public class StringProperty : ItemProperty
{
    public string RawProp { get; set; }
    public string RenderedProp { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to get the RenderedProp value like so (assuming the dictionary variable is called Properties):

```
string value = Properties[keyname];
```

versus

```
string value = Properties[keyname].RenderedProp;
```

Comment: believe this code `string value = Properties[keyname].RenderedProp;` get compile error

Comment: why would you possibly want to do this?

Comment: for 85% of the times I would need to call this I would only want the renderedProp...however there are times when I woudl want the raw one..instead of calling the renderedprop all the time, I thought it would be cleaner to just default to that property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own `PropertyDictionary` with a custom Indexer method.

```
public class PropertyDictionary
{
    Dictionary <string, StringProperty> dictionary;

    public PropertyDictionary()
    {
        dictionary = new Dictionary <string, StringProperty>();
    }

    // Indexer; returns RenderedProp instead of Value
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return dictionary[key].RenderedProp; }
        set { dictionary[key].RenderedProp = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for...is there a reason why this would not be recommended or bad practice?

Comment: As you use composition, you have to implement all of the basic Methods like Add() and Remove() all over again.

Comment: It doesn't have to be composition.  You can inherit from `Dictionary<K,V>` if you want to sort that all out; this is just an example of the indexer.

Comment: This seems to be having trouble as RenderedProp is not an actual object, but a property name (a string) in the ItemProperty object.

Comment: You mean the `StringProperty` object, right?  I made a couple of changes to the code.  The indexer should be returning a `string`, not a RenderedProp.

Comment: it still can't resolve the dictionary[key] for some reason..even return "" claims a } is missing

Comment: Well, that's a compiler error.  I made another fix to the code, in the constructor.

Comment: the trick was that it was needing a `get { return dictionary[key].RenderedProp }`

Answer (score 3):

No. If you want to store the `RenderedProp` value in the dictionary, just make it a `Dictionary<string, string>` and add it appropriately. If you *do* actually need the full `ItemProperties` in the dictionary, but frequently want to get at the `RenderedProp`, you could always create a method to do that (wherever the dictionary lives).

Note that if `RenderedProp` is *only* specified in `StringProperty` (not in other subclasses of `ItemProperties`) then you need to consider what would happen for non-StringProperty values in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution, but I would strongly recommend against it: define an implicit conversion operator from `StringProperty` to `string`, and return `RenderedProp` to the caller:

```
public class StringProperty : ItemProperty
{
    public string RawProp { get; set; }
    public string RenderedProp { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator string(StringProperty p)
    {
        return p.RenderedProp;
    }
}
```

The `Dictionary` needs to use `StringProperty`, not `ItemProperty` as the value type in order for the operator to apply. The same is true about your `Properties[keyname].RenderedProp` code as well.

Comment: interesting, why is it not recommended thought?

Comment: @Scottingham I recommend against this solution because implicit conversion operators like the above make it much harder to read the code that relies on them. People unfamiliar with your code would spend some time scratching their heads before they understand what is really going on. That's a bad thing, especially when you deal with large code bases.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement an extension method for your Dictionary<>:

```
public static int GetRP(this Dictionary <string, ItemProperties> dict, string key)
{
    return dict[key].RenderedProp;
}
```

You'd have to call it directly though, without having the indexer notation. Overall code is similarly short if you use a short name.